# React Form submits automatically, prevent automatic submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a form which has a rich text editor and a form submit button, the rich text editor has style buttons which when clicked submit the form inputs (which is not desirable).

I want to prevent this behaviour I want the form to submit only when the submit button is clicked and not when the RTE style button is clicked.

**Code:-**

[Form Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-volhard-d1b7qy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You can stop the click event from bubbling out of the component you're in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: In HeadingStyleControls.js set button types to button like <button type="button" .. /> . Default behavior of the button is submit if its inside <form /> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved the RichEditor out of the form.
You can still handle the form submit,
I've added the onClick listener on submit button itself.
**Just copy and paste this return statement in your App.js**

```
return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form>
          <label htmlFor="contact">
            Full Name <span id="required-input-star">*</span>
          </label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="contact">
            Email <span id="required-input-star">*</span>
          </label>
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            required
          />

          <br />
          <label htmlFor="description">
            Description <span id="required-input-star">*</span>
          </label>
          <br />
        </form> //closed the form here, and moved out RichEditor


       <RichTextEditor />

        <hr />
        <div className="frm-btn-container">
          <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="cancel-btn" />
          <input type="submit" value="Create" onClick={onSubmit} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the button text editor's button.